# difference between どの and どちらの

Tags: word-choice

> 息子さんは**どちらの**学校ヘ通っていますか。
>
> 息子さんは**どの**学校ヘ通っていますか。

Could someone tell me the difference between どの and どちら in this case?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14998/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16069/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/25745/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

どちら is more polite and formal than どの.

If the person you are talking to is someone you want to show a level of politeness or respect to then どちら is a good choice. どの would not be considered rude or casual, though.

Comment: でも・・・"Where do you go to school?" (in the sense of "Which school do you go to?") って聞くとき、「 **どちらの**学校に通ってい(らっしゃい)ますか。」「 **どこの**学校に通ってますか。」とは言いますけど、「 **どの**学校に通ってますか」って言わないですよね・・・